# page crash in IE 11 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I am facing page crash in IE 11 on form submit.My application is in sharepoint. In all other browser and even in older versions of IE he site works perfect.
[image]

What can be the problem? Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: I'd say it's a bug in IE11 not your site, try it on a different computer.

Comment: Actually I've tested it on different systems.I got mixed results.It works on some systems and does not work on others. :(

Comment: I find it funny that a site made using Microsoft's framework crashes their browser, maybe link to the site and someone with more IE/ASP.Net experience could help.